# React-router v2: how to use the 'replace' function in callbacks

Tags: react-router, meteor-accounts

When using "onEnter" property in React-router, the **replace()** function doesn't work for me in callbacks. It works fine when it is called in a synchronous way (not in callbacks):

```
function verifyEmail(nextState, replace) {
     replace({pathname: '/list'});
}

<Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/verify-email/:token" component={AppNotFound} onEnter={verifyEmail}/>
</Route>
```

However, it stops working when it is used in callbacks like this:

```
function verifyEmail(nextState, replace) {
    console.log("replace", replace);
    Accounts.verifyEmail( nextState.params.token, function(error){
        if ( error ) {
            console.log(error.reason);
        } else {
            console.log("verified successfully!");
            replace({pathname: '/list'});
        }
    });
}

<Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/verify-email/:token" component={AppNotFound} onEnter={verifyEmail}/>
</Route>
```

The console log will show "verified successfully", but it doesn't actually redirect the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to pass in a third parameter "callback" for verifyEmail function, since the method is async.

See the doc here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

> **onEnter(nextState, replace, callback?)**
>
> Called when a route is about to be entered. It provides the next
>   router state and a function to redirect to another path. this will be
>   the route instance that triggered the hook.
>
> If callback is listed as a 3rd argument, this hook will run
>   asynchronously, and the transition will block until callback is
>   called.

So your code should be:

```
function verifyEmail(nextState, replace, callback) {
    console.log("replace", replace);
    Accounts.verifyEmail( nextState.params.token, function(error){
        if ( error ) {
            console.log(error.reason);
            callback(); //When async finishes, do the redirect
        } else {
            console.log("verified successfully!");
            replace({pathname: '/list'});
            callback(); //When async finishes, do the redirect
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for writing about Callback function, In my program, Replace was working when called directly inside the function but it just wouldn't work when called inside .then(), executing callback inside Promise solved the problem

Comment: Hi, I have a similar project using react-router v2 as well. Except my async  method is used to generate a string which would be passed into  getDisplayName of that route. Can you please help and advise how i can do this?